# Emulator show error

Tags: android, android-emulator

My emulator runs normal just that error appear at event log .This happen after I upgrade to android 3.0.

> 10/28/2017
>   8:00 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 8:00 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
>
> 8:00 PM    Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
>
> 8:00 PM    Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
>
> 8:00 PM    Gradle build finished in 27s 960ms

Comment: I think I found the problem. i din activate VT-d in bios of my skylake cpu.